# How to access a file in public reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

How can I access the js file inside the public.
I want to write the api addresses in that file and call it in the fetch.
Idont want use enviroment becuase cant change address after build.
I can not call the address inside the file in the fetch.
please guide me

Comment: What type of file would you like to access?

Comment: I have a js file  in public and  defined two url inside that and I want to call them in the fetch.now I cant undrestant how do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I triyed with, process.env.PUBLIC_URL  and /Address.js . Does not read js files. Maybe I went the wrong way. Thank you for your help